# Find area of a curved surface within a condition

Tags: area, surface-integrals

> Curved surface **r** given by $\mathbf{r}=(u+v,u-v,uv)^T$. Calculate
>   area of a part of the curved surface that satisfies $u^2 + v^2 \leq 1$

Here what I have done:

$\mathbf{r}_u=\frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial u}= (1, 1, v)^T$

$\mathbf{r}_v=\frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial u}= (1, 1, v)^T$

Hence
$\mathbf{r}_u \times\ \mathbf{r}_v = (u + v, -u + v, -2)^T$

And
$|\mathbf{r}_u \times\ \mathbf{r}_v| = \sqrt{(2(u^2 + v^2 + 2)}$

Then the area should be

$$S = \iint_D|\mathbf{r}_u \times\ \mathbf{r}_v|dudv=\iint_D\sqrt{(2(u^2 + v^2 + 2)}dudv$$

Let $u = r\cos\theta$, $v = r\sin\theta$ then $r^2 = u^2 + v^2$,
$u^2 + v^2 \leq 1$ give $-1\leq r\leq 1$.

Thus

$$S =\iint_D\sqrt{(2(u^2 + v^2 + 2)}dudv = \int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\int_{-1}^1\sqrt{(2(r^2 + 2)}rdr=0 (!?)$$

Anything wrong with my calculation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limits for $r$ should be from 0 to 1 rather than from $-1$ to 1.
$$S=\int_0^1\int_0^{2\pi}r\sqrt{2(r^2+2)}\,d\theta\,dr$$
$$=\int_0^12\pi r\sqrt{2(r^2+2)}\,dr$$
$$=\frac\pi2\int_0^14r\sqrt{2(r^2+2)}\,dr$$
$$=\frac\pi2\left[\frac23(2(r^2+2))^{3/2}\right]_0^1=\pi\left(2\sqrt6-\frac83\right)=7.013\dots$$

Comment: Why? Because r have to be positive?

Comment: @nghia95 Yes, this is polar coordinates!

Comment: Oh really? I didn't know that. Thank you so much!